# belongsToMany not associating two models - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have 2 models, with belongsToMany. I'm following [laravel eloquent documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships).

**Employee model**

```
class Employee extends \Eloquent {
    function tags() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Tag','Tags_Employees');
    }
}
```

**Tag Model**

```
class Tag extends \Eloquent {

    function employees() {
        $this->belongsToMany('Employee','Tags_Employees');
    }
}
```

**I have 3 tables:**

```
Tags (string: name, inc: id) 

Employees (string: name, int: id)

Tags_Employees (int:id, int: tag_id, int: employee_id).
```

I'm trying to extract the Tags that belongs to the user in EmployeeConroller:

```
$employee = Employee::find(15);
$tags = $employee->tags;

View::share('employee',$employee);
View::share('tags',$tags);
return View::make('employee/index');
```

The `tags` is null and i can't understand why, i double checked the db and i do have entries in Tags_Employees that connects between the employee and the tag. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: try dd($employee) to check if it returns correct model, if so, then check the queries that laravel runs after $employee->tags. For example with DB::getQueryLog()

Comment: You have forgot the `return` when defining the belongsToMany relationship in the Tag Model